# Show SQL Database with same group appeared twice or more

Tags: mysql

Have been looking hours for this and I couldn't find anything related so I'll ask instead. I have a database like this:

```
id |  date     | name  
 1 |2017-01-01 | sarah  
 2 |2017-01-02 | sarah  
 3 |2017-01-03 | john  
 4 |2017-01-04 | john   
 5 |2017-01-05 | john  
 6 |2017-01-06 | sarah  
 7 |2017-01-07 | sarah  
 8 |2017-01-08 | eddy  
 9 |2017-01-09 | eddy
```

I want to make a list like below:

```
start date | end date   | name  
2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 | sarah  
2017-01-03 | 2017-01-05 | john  
2017-01-06 | 2017-01-07 | sarah  
2017-01-08 | 2017-01-09 | eddy
```

How can I achieve this? Have been trying to use:

```
SELECT MIN(date) as mindate, MAX(date) as maxdate, name
FROM 'table'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY date DESC
```

but I getting these instead:

```
start date | end date   | name   
2017-01-01 | 2017-01-07 | sarah   
2017-01-03 | 2017-01-05 | john    
2017-01-08 | 2017-01-09 | eddy
```

Please note that in the list I want, the name SARAH appeared twice and with GROUP BY, Sarah only appeared once...

Comment: What's the rule to determine if date is a start or end date?

Comment: @DaveCoast The `id` determines the gaps and islands.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a row number variable to identify the starting and ending dates for each island.  The end result is similar logic to what you had intended originally, except that now we are taking the start and end dates for each *island*, rather than for each name across the entire table.

```
SET @island_number = 0;
SET @name = '';

SELECT MIN(t.date) AS start_date,
       MAX(t.date) AS end_date,
       t.name
FROM
(
    SELECT @island_number:=CASE WHEN @name = name
                                THEN @island_number
                                ELSE @island_number + 1
                           END AS gn,
           @name:=name AS name,
           date
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY id
) t
GROUP BY t.gn, t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query.

```
SELECT
MIN(_date) as start_date
,MAX(_date) as end_date
,name_new as name
FROM
(
Select
   _date
   ,if(name = @prev, @seq, @seq := @seq + 1) as seq
   ,if(name = @prev, name, @prev := name) as name_new
From test, (SELECT @seq := 0, @prev := '') AS init
Order by `_date`
  ) as der
  group by name_new, seq
  order by seq
```